# Join table with almost same data

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables, each table having one column(datatype=char). First table has 3 rows all single A's, second table has 5 rows all Single A's. What will be the result of inner join, left join, right join, full outer join.
I know the result but i want to understand how it works in detail.

Comment: Don't be lazy. Try the different joins, or google, or both.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: @sridhar: if you want you can initiate chat with me or someone else. Join is a chapter in itself and it can't be explained here. Another option is to find a good book. Another is to find explaination for each join on google. Read each explaination. Some or other will definitely work for you. Off course you will have to create tables, insert data into them and run queries. As #jarlh has said BE ACTIVE.

Comment: Try the new documentation section http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join#t=201608041157420184702

Answer (score 0):

When there are matching rows in both tables, there is no difference between any of those types of joins. They will give identical results: one result row for each combination of matching left-hand rows and right-hand rows.

The different types of joins are relevant when you ***do*** have a particular value in one table and ***do not*** have it in the other.

If you want to include rows from the left-hand table even if there are no matching right-hand rows, you'd use `LEFT JOIN`. Likewise you'd use `RIGHT JOIN` when you want to match the other way around: include all right-hand rows, even if there are no matching left-hand rows.

And when you only want to include rows for which there ***is*** a match, you'd use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks @VoteyDisciple